# Find cities reachable in given time

Tags: algorithm, scala, graph-theory

I am trying to solve a problem where i have 3 columns in csv like below

```
connection             Distance          Duration
Prague<>Berlin         400               4
Warsaw<>Berlin         600               6
Berlin<>Munich         800               8
Munich<>Vienna         400               3.5
Munich<>Stuttgart      800               8
Stuttgart<>Freiburg    150               2
```

I need to find out how many cities i can cover in given time from the origin city

Example if i would give input as

> **Input: Berlin, 10**
>
> **Output: ["Prague","Munich","Warsaw"]**

> **Input : Berlin, 30**
>
> **Output : ["Prague","Munich","Warsaw", "Vienna", "Stuttgart",
> "Freiburg"]**

This is something a Graph problem in real time.
I am trying this with Scala, can someone help please.

Below what i tried:

I made it working partially.

```
import scalax.collection.Graph // or scalax.collection.mutable.Graph
import scalax.collection.GraphPredef._, scalax.collection.GraphEdge._
import scalax.collection.edge.WDiEdge
import scalax.collection.edge.Implicits._

val rows = """Prague<>Berlin,400,4
Warsaw<>Berlin,600,6
Berlin<>Munich,800,8
Munich<>Vienna,400,3.5
Munich<>Stuttgart,800,8
Stuttgart<>Freiburg,150,2""".split("\n").toList
```

I am preparing the input for my application.
Below i am having a list of cities which are present in the given file.

NOTE: We can have it from file itself while reading and kept in list. Here i kept all as lowercase

```
val cityList = List("warsaw","berlin","prague","munich","vienna","stuttgart","freiburg")
```

Now creating a case class:

```
case class Bus(connection: String, distance: Int, duration: Float)


val buses: List[Bus] = rows.map(row => {
  val r =
 row.split("\\,")
  Bus(r(0).toLowerCase, r(1).toInt, r(2).toFloat)
})

case class City(name: String)
// case class BusMeta(distance: Int, duration: Float)

val t = buses.map(bus => {
  val s = bus.connection.split("<>")
  City(s.head) ~ City(s.last) % bus.duration
})

val busGraph = Graph(t:_*)
```

From above we will create a Graph as required from the input file. "busGraph" in my case.

```
import scala.collection.mutable
 
val travelFrom = ("BERLIN").toLowerCase
val travelDuration = 16F
val possibleCities: mutable.Set[String] = mutable.Set()


if (cityList.contains(travelFrom)){
  busGraph.nodes.get(City(travelFrom)).edges.filter(_.weight <= travelDuration).map(edge => edge.map(_.name)).flatten.toSet.filterNot(_ == travelFrom).foreach(possibleCities.add)
  println("City PRESENT in File")
}
else
{
  println("City Not Present in File")
}
```

I am geting Output here :

```
possibleCities: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = Set(munich, warsaw, prague)


Expected Output : Set(munich, warsaw, prague, stuttgart, Vienna)
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working for you?

Comment: Um ... your input file is not csv - tab separated values perhaps?

Comment: My bad, but its a CSV file and not tab, in posting question it looks like tab seperated.

Comment: Homework help questions are generally welcome on SO, but "please do my homework for me" are not. You should take a stub at solving the problem yourself, and come  back with a concrete question if you run into something you cannot figure out on your own. Also note that the answers you offer to both your sample inputs are incorrect: there is no route from Prague to Munich in your example

Comment: @Dima : Thanks for the reply, Yes i tried the way out already but i failed to edit here. Now i have edited. Thanks for response

Also the graph is bidirectional.

Comment: @HEMANTPATEL I'm not really confident in correctness of task you posted (or example outputs). For example you give an example that with Berlin 10 - you can reach 3 cities (which is in total gives more than 10). Could you please clarify how 10 limits number of cities?

Comment: @Maksym Each of the 3 cities is reachable from Berlin within 10 time units (although not in the same trip).

Comment: @Olivier Got it thanks,see my answer below with algorithm explanation, Im not a Java guy, but approach should work :)

Answer (score 4):

Your solution only finds direct routes (that's why your output is shorter than expected). To get complete answer, you need to also consider connections, by recursively traversing the graph from each of the direct destinations.

Also, do not use mutable collections, they are evil.

Here is a possible solution for you:

```
// First, create the graph structure
  def routes: Map[String, (String, Double)] = Source
    .fromInputStream(System.in)
    .getLines
    .takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)
    .map(_.split("\\s+"))
    .flatMap { case Array(from_to, dist, time) =>
      val Array(from,to) = from_to.split("<>")
      Seq(from -> (to, time.toDouble), to -> (from, time.toDouble))
    }.toSeq
    .groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
  

  // Now search for suitable routes
  def reachable(
    routes: Map[String, Seq[(String, Double)]],
    from: String,
    limit: Double,
    cut: Set[String] = Set.empty
  ): Set[String] = routes
    .getOrElse(from, Nil)
    .filter(_._2 <= limit)
    .filterNot { case (n, _) => cut(n) }
    .flatMap { case(name, time) => 
       reachable(routes, name, limit - time, cut + from) + name 
    }.toSet
    
  // And here is how you use it
  def main(argv: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val Array(from, limit) = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split("\\s")
    val reach = reachable(routes, from, limit.toDouble)
    println(reach)
  }
```

Comment: Recursion is an alternative path, the academic way is dynamic programming https://www.programiz.com/dsa/dynamic-programming

Comment: @Maksym this isn't a very good example of a DP problem, specifically because it is too primitive to demonstrate (or use) its power. You don't need the entire matrix of costs saved here, just the current path. It is very much like the second implementation of the fibonacci numbers in the article you linked: in a way, is a DP solution too, just simple enough for you to not recognize it.

Comment: The task is very simple, which is very true. I'm not sure that fibonacci  is a correct comparison, for me this sounds as find all paths in graph that match weight criteria, which is quite different.

Comment: @Maksym advantage of DP is avoiding repeated calculations (by memoization in a typical DP solution). Here every path is computed once, so there is no repetition (and thus no need for "full-blown" DP). Same as with Fibonacci numbers. That's the similarity I mentioned.

Comment: Ahh, I see where the misconception coming from. Avoiding same calculations multiple times is not the only reason for DP(while most common). There are many ways to use it, but the idea remain the same you will memorize interim results. The same concept can be used with Graph tasks, if you memorise results appropriately you can use linear checks of possible routes, instead of traversing the tree (recursion). Generally I'm against of recursion mightily always and prefer linear-easy to measure algorithms. But that's philosophy

Comment: @Maksym It is not a misconception. There is no reason to memorize intermediate results unless you are going to use them again. Memorizing things you only need once (or don't need at all)  is wasteful, and never makes for a good algorithm  (that's kinda what the first implementation of fibnacci does in your article). 
Traversing the tree _is_ linear. Recursion is not an algorithm, it's just a technique. Anything done with recursion can be rewritten as a loop, its just more cumbersome, but computationally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Do a breadth first search from the origin city, stopping going deeper when you reach the time limit.  Output the stops reached by the search.

Comment: You don't need breadth-first search here.
 
A depth-limited depth-first search would find exactly the same set of cities reachable within a given time limit, but it wouldn't need any extra queue data structures, it could just reuse the call stack. Since you care only about the reachable cities, not about the shortest time you'd need to reach them, there is no need for BFS.

Just do a simple depth-limited DFS.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure whether this is even being asked here. But BFS doesn't seem to buy you anything in any case.

Comment: BFS is for trees. We have a graph here.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyTyukin for input, I tried some way similar but its not 100% working for me. Edited tried steps in question.

Comment: @ravenspoint BFS is not the right path, Graph use different algorithms

Answer (score -1):

To my best knowledge this tasks should be solved with Graph Adjacency Matrix, which first need to build from input data.

In your particular case the Graph Adjacency Matrix would be 2D and contains cities on rows and columns and weight of direction as value.

See screenshot from Excel with example below,

At the first iteration you search for possible routes from starting cities and store city name (row/column id) and weight.

Each next iteration you try to add route and compare with limit (can you add it or not also make sure you are not adding same city)

To store results you will need again 2D array, where first element is you possible route and next element is a Tuple of visited city and value taken.

After few iterations you should get all possible options and just provide summary of founded.

[image]

TL;DR; Most of Graph programmatical algorithms use or depends (with different extent) on Graph Adjacency Matrix